# Python nested dictionary assignment not working

Tags: python, dictionary

The code in question is [here on Github](https://github.com/IamCarbonMan/PoGoMsgBot/blob/master/bot.py). Basically, everything is working except the [addClient( )](https://github.com/IamCarbonMan/PoGoMsgBot/blob/master/bot.py#L35) function, which takes a SRE_Match object and parses it, then assigns the extracted variables in a dict, to a key in a globally defined dict. But after it has created this new key, when it prints the item associated with that key, it throws a KeyError saying that the key is not defined! I have no idea what is going on with this.

The code for addClient( ):

```
def addClient(client, info,medium):
if info:
    info = info.group(0).split(' ')
    if medium == 'text':
        db['clients']['text'][client] = {'number':info[0],'os':info[1]}
    elif medium == 'email':
        db['clients']['email'][client] = {'address':info[0],'os':info[1]}
    elif medium == 'pm':
        db['clients']['pm'][client] = {'os':info[0]}
print(db['clients'][medium][client])
```

Comment: You need to show a self-contained example demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Please post the relevant code in your question and show what steps you have taken to debug so far.

Comment: Then `medium` isn't hitting any of your three cases, or `info` is false. Since you have paths through the function which can result in the keys not being set, but you try to print it regardless, it seems quite likely you're hitting one of those paths.

Comment: `medium` is one of those three, I can guarantee that.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the answer should have been obvious. As TesselatingHeckler suggested, the error pops up when `info` is not true, and can be fixed like:

```
def addClient(client, info,medium):
if info:
    info = info.group(0).split(' ')
    if medium == 'text':
        db['clients']['text'][client] = {'number':info[0],'os':info[1]}
    elif medium == 'email':
        db['clients']['email'][client] = {'address':info[0],'os':info[1]}
    elif medium == 'pm':
        db['clients']['pm'][client] = {'os':info[0]}
    print(db['clients'][medium][client])
```